Why do monoidal functors between categories of quasicoherent sheaves commute with external tensor products
I'm reading Lurie's paper on Tannaka duality for geometric stacks. Very roughly, my question is, why do monoidal functors, from which we try to build geometric morphisms, commute with certain algebra actions? This is done in Section 9.
Some preliminaries

Let $U$ be an affine scheme given by $\textrm{Spec}A$. Assume that we have a 1-stack with affine diagonal given by $p: U\to \mathcal{X}.$
Let $B$ be the global sections of the structure sheaf of $U\times_\mathcal{X} U$. Since $\mathcal{X}$ has an affine diagonal $U\times_\mathcal{X} U$ is also affine.
$F^*$ is a monoidal functor from $QCoh(\mathcal{X})$ to $QCoh(S)$ for some affine scheme $S$. It is also assumed to be tame (a technical condition about flatness), but I don't think this is relevant to any of my questions.
Denote by $\mathcal{A}$ the object $F^*p_*\mathcal{O}_U$ in the category $QCoh(S)$.

Question: I'm confused by the following passage from Section 9 (top of page 12 on arXiv).



In particular,

Why we have the following equivalence of sheaves $p_*\mathcal{O}_U\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{X}}p_*\mathcal{O}_U\simeq p_*\mathcal{O}_U\otimes_A B.$
Why does $F^*$ commute with external tensor products (i.e. why does commuting with colimits imply that)?
How part 2 implies that $F^*(p_*\mathcal{O}_U\otimes_A B)\simeq F^*p_*\mathcal{O}_U\otimes_A B$? That is why this equivalence is related to external tensor products.

Thank you in advance, and I am sorry if my questions are too simple.
